# how to add additional information when to submit app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Now, I am going to submit my app for approving. The problem is that, when the first time logging the app, you have to enter a verification code provided by me (by email or oral to my target user). So how can I give the code for approving.

May be I could set a default verification code programmatically, but when the app is approved , I have to update the app to disable the default verification code and this lead to another approve process.

So, can someone give me some advice to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're in iTunesConnect preparing to submit your app there's a box for review notes ([Source](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf), page 49), where you can put a verification code for the reviewers to use.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes Connect provides an area for Review Notes. The app tester will look at this and use it during review.

Simply put the verification code and any other information inside that area. they WILL read it.